# How do I make a Reads[T] for an optional value

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, deserialization

I have a field called "name" in my JSON. There are three states that this could be:

- null/undefined
- an empty string
- a non-empty string

I would like this to come out of the serializer as Option[NonEmptyString]

I have implemented Reads[NonEmptyString], which reads a String (with minimum length 1) and then puts it in the container class (NonEmptyString)

If I use readNullable, then the empty string will throw an exception when I attempt to convert it to a NonEmptyString.

If I implement a Reads[Option[NonEmptyString]] this does not work, presumably because Play treats Option as a special case

How do I implement the Reads that does what I want?

Answer (score 1):

`(JsPath \ "key").reads[Option[NonEmptyString]]`

This works because unlike readsNullable, it does not require the value to be deserialized correctly if it is present